# How to remove properties of mongo objects in an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I hope the snippets below make my question more clearer. I can fetch an object that has embedded an array of category objects. From the category objects I want to show only certain properties.

So this is what I get now:

```
{
  "photo": [],
  "_id": "5ec55ae39eere8ert85bf8fe749",
  "title": "Blog about coding",
  "description": "Hi, I want to share with you my incredible journey as a software developer...",
  "rate": 3,
  "category": [
    {
      "_id": "5ec55ae39aaa78985f8fe74a",
      "name": "programming",
      "display_name": "Programming"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-05-20T16:29:23.982Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T16:29:23.982Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

With the following code:

```
/* GET blog with id */
router.get("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const blog = await Blog.findById(req.params.id); // How to filter out fields of objects in category array?
        res.send(blog);
    } catch(ex) {
        res.status(400).send(ex); 
    }
});
```

This is what I actually want:

```
{
  "photo": [],
  "_id": "5ec55ae39eere8ert85bf8fe749",
  "title": "Blog about coding",
  "description": "Hi, I want to share with you my incredible journey as a software developer...",
  "rate": 3,
  "category": [
    {
      "display_name": "Programming"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-05-20T16:29:23.982Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-20T16:29:23.982Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

So, in category I want only the "display_name"

How can I get this. I thought I saw a solution before, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `.findById()` which is mongoose wrapper to `.findOne({_id: ObjectId()})` which offloads burden of converting input string to `ObjectId()`, but there is nothing much `.find()`'s can help on projection, You need to list all the fields as like given below :

```
/** .findById(inputString, projection) */

Blog.findById(req.params.id,
{
  "category.display_name": 1,
  "title": 1,
  "description": 1,
  "rate": 1,
  "createdAt": 1,
  "updatedAt": 1
})

/** Or */

Blog.findById(req.params.id,
{
  "category._id": 0,
  "category.name": 0,
})
```

**Test :** As playground can't use `.findById` test it using `.find()` :  [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G7Eay11KnhQ)

But if you lean towards using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) you can do lot more in projection :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

/* GET blog with id */
router.get("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const blog = await Blog.aggregate([{$match : {_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}},
            { $addFields: { category: { $map: { input: "$category", in: { display_name: "$$this.display_name" } } } } }
        ]);
        res.send(blog);
    } catch(ex) {
        res.status(400).send(ex); 
    }
});
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2rEUVDcn6_3)

**Note :** This aggregation query iterates thru `category` array and keep only `display_name` in each object, Use this pipeline only if you need to exclude a lot of fields in `category` objects. I would suggest to use second option in `.findById()` cause you no need to convert `string` to `ObjectId()` and an aggregation pipeline just to exclude fields `name` and `_id` inside objects of category array.

Comment: Where is the part of aggregate? :P Thnx my friend, you really helped me.

Comment: @AndaluZ : Updated maybe you give it a try and check differences and choose better one :-)

Comment: Thnx for the explanation about the aggregation method. Yes, excluding properties in .findById() is the simplest solution for me now.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a schema for your Blog collection and then customize the toJSON method for deleting the properties you want to hide like this:

```
BlogSchema.methods.toJSON = function callback() {

  const blog = this;
  const blogObject = blog.toObject();

  delete blogObject._id;
  delete blogObject.name;

  return blogObject;
};
```

I use this approach to hide sensible data such as passwords when sending back the users their info!

Comment: You can of course do this in code, but the better part would be to exclude unnecessary fields while extracting data from DB (Why to get all fields over the network if not needed), Excluding helps a lot while working with huge datasets, less data to be iterated/retrieved/worked-on gives us much more performance benefits :-)

Comment: You're right! I'm just starting with node and mongo though, and there are many many things I don't know how to do properly yet. Just thought maybe this might help other newbies like me.Thanks for both your comment and your answer, they helped me a lot! :)